# Allow https Web Api connections

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, https, asp.net-web-api

How  to  enable only  https  connections to mvc4 Web Api functions ?

**Update:**

Is it possible yet https connections in api controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would one of these work for you? http://www.sslshopper.com/iis7-redirect-http-to-https.html

Comment: very usefull link +1.But my question is a bit different - (I am not spesialist in this things so forgive me possible simple mistakes) -1. is mvc 4 web api framework allows yet https? 2. How to enable on programming level this?

Comment: It's not a programming-level problem. HTTPS must be handled by IIS with a certificate. For development, a self-signed cert will be fine. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx For production, you need a real cert from a trusted certificate authority.